# Sort and print in a table multidimensional array array in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to print this full multidimensional array in a table and sort it by name [A-Z].

```
//Example not sorted:
//Id - Name - Last name -      Email        - Phone number
   2 - Bldo -  Surname  - email@example.com - 23452524352
   6 - Cldo -  Surname  - email@example.com - 23452524352
   3 - Aldo -  Surname  - email@example.com - 23452524352

//Example sorted:
//Id - Name - Last name -       Email       - Phone Number
   3 - Aldo -  Surname  - email@example.com - 23452524352
   2 - Bldo -  Surname  - email@example.com - 23452524352
   6 - Cldo -  Surname  - email@example.com - 23452524352
```

Here is the array.

```
// Array with the contacts details
$contacts = array (

    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2
        [1] => "Bldo" 
        [2] => "Surname" 
        [3] => "email@example.com"
        [4] => 3243125152 
    )

    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 6
        [1] => "Cldo" 
        [2] => "Surname" 
        [3] => "email@example.com"
        [4] => 3243125152 
    ) 

    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3
        [1] => "Aldo" 
        [2] => "Surname" 
        [3] => "email@example.com"
        [4] => 3243125152 
    ) 
);
```

Here is the html.

```
<?php
    <!-- Resoults from db -->
    <table> 

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Checkbox</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone number</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <?php
            // Print contacts here
            ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>
?>
```

I tried only with one array and it works, but I can't figure it out how to make it with the multidimensional array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: You can use PHP function array_multisort. In the examples, you find enough suggestions how to use it. For example, have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#114076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating an array with values of what you want to sort by, in this case by name.
Then assign the values of `$contacts` to an array where the keys will be **names** and values will be the **contacts values**
Then you only need to sort the results and it's done.

```
$contacts = array (
    array(2,"Bldo","Surname","email@example.com",3243125152),
    array(6,"Cldo","Surname","email@example.com",3243125152),
    array(2,"Aldo","Surname","email@example.com",3243125152));

$names = array();
foreach($contacts as $contact) {
    array_push($names,$contact[1]);
}

$result = array();
foreach($names as $key => $val) {
    $result[$val] = $contacts[$key];
}

array_multisort($result);

print_r($result);
```

Try this.

Comment: If you want you can avoid the first foreach and use only $names = array_column($contacts, '1');

Answer (score 0):

Create [your own sorting function](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/usort.php) and apply it on the array.

Then

```
    <tbody>
        <?php
          foreach ($contact as &$value) {
            //do what you want with your contact ($value)
          }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data sorting could be done with [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) functions [Demo](https://3v4l.org/YVhPU):

```
$keys = array_column($contacts, 1);
array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $contacts);
```

In table you can use simple `foreach`. Put next between `tbody` tags:

```
<?php foreach($contacts as $record): ?>
 <tr>
    <?php foreach($record as $item): ?>
         <td><?= $item; ?></td> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
         <td>..stuff for update button..</td>
 </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```